# I'm trying to hide active applications from the dock in OSX Sierra but what I'm doing just crashes the application

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-app-extension

I did some research on the subject and theoretically you should be able to insert

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true>
```

right before

```
</dict>
</plist>
```

at the end of a .dmg file to get the icon to hide from the dock even when it is in use. I'm not looking for a workaround like "Change the dock icon" or "Just hide the dock entirely" or something like that, I'd like to know how this sort of thing works and why it is just crashing the application rather than hiding the dock icon.

Comment: You would add that to the Info.plist, not to the .dmg, and it generally works. What is the crash you are getting? When are you getting it? What is the crash log? The trace? Does anything log to the console? It's completely impossible to help with the dearth of information in this question.

Comment: I figured it out, LSUIElement apparently just crashes some applications, but a workaround that performs the same thing is NSUIelement instead of LSUIelement. I love that I spent hours researching this and then found the correct answer 2 minutes after asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, LSUIElement apparently just crashes some applications, but a workaround that performs the same thing is NSUIelement instead of LSUIelement. I love that I spent hours researching this and then found the correct answer 2 minutes after asking.